# PySpark add row of arrays together until limit is reached

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark Dataframe with a column where each row contains an array of integers with an arbitrary length.
What I would like to do is reduce the number of rows by combining these lists together until each array in each row has a length of `n` that I will need to use as a parameter. By combining these lists, I mean if row 1 has a length of 4 and `n = 5`, the first element of the list in row 2 should be added to row 1 and removed from row 2. Then, continue until there are no more rows/elements left. If the last row's array does not have a length of `n`, it must be filled with zeros.
Example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                            (2, [6, 7, 8]),
                            (3, [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]),
                            (4, [14, 15]),
                            (5, [16, 17, 18]),
                            (6, [19, 20, 21])],
                           ['id', 'col'])
```

Desired output:

```
+---+----------------+
|id |col             |
+---+----------------+
|1  |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |
|2  |[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]|
|3  |[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]|
|4  |[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]|
|5  |[21, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
+---+----------------+
```

I have been trying to use groupBy with a custom aggregation function but I can't really see how can I implement the limitation logic. I was also thinking exploding each element into separate rows but it might not be an optimal solution performance-wise as I'm dealing with large amounts of data.

Any clues on how this could be solved would be highly appreciated.